# Как сделать кнопки + и - в opencart2 в карточке товара?

Tags: php, javascript, opencart

Перепробовал несколько модулей, ничего. Пробовал эту статью [Добавление + и -](http://jul-collection.com/opencart-pole-kolichestva-tovara-v-kartochke-tovara-dobavlyaem-plyus-i-minus.html)

Не помогло. Количество добавляет, но при нажатии на кнопку купить, всеравно думает что там один товар, а не то количество которое в поле

Answer (score 0):

Не самый кавайный подход, но у меня работает.

product.tpl:

```
<div class=" col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between;align-items:baseline;margin-bottom:10px">
                <i class="fa fa-minus fa-2x form-control col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 hover-green" aria-hidden="true" onmouseup="decrementValue('input-quantity',1,'dynamic-price',<?=$discount['quantity'];?>,<?=$discount['percentage'];?>);" style="border:0"></i>
                <input oninput="validateQty(this,'number',1,99);" disabled="disabled" type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" min="1" max="99" size="2" id="input-quantity" class="form-control col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 text-center" />
                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x form-control col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 hover-green" aria-hidden="true" onmouseup="incrementValue('input-quantity',99,'dynamic-price',<?=$discount['quantity'];?>,<?=$discount['percentage'];?>);" style="border:0"></i>
            </div>
```

common.js:

```
function incrementValue(el,flow,ch,dq,dp) {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById(el).value, 10);
  var arr_ch = document.getElementsByClassName(ch);
  var start;
  value = (value >= flow) ? flow : value + 1;
  if( value < flow){
    for(i=0;i<arr_ch.length;i++){
        start = Number(arr_ch[i].getAttribute('data-start'));
        if(value >= dq){
            arr_ch[i].innerHTML = (value * (start - start * dp)).toFixed(2);
            $('#discount-detector').addClass('light-me-green');
        }else{
            arr_ch[i].innerHTML = (value * start).toFixed(2);
        }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById(el).value = value;
}
function decrementValue(el,flow,ch,dq,dp) {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById(el).value, 10);
  var arr_ch = document.getElementsByClassName(ch);
  var start;
  if(value > 1){
    for(i=0;i<arr_ch.length;i++){
        start = Number(arr_ch[i].getAttribute('data-start'));
        if(value > dq){
            arr_ch[i].innerHTML = (Number(arr_ch[i].innerHTML) - (start - start * dp)).toFixed(2);
        }else{
            arr_ch[i].innerHTML = ((start * value) - start).toFixed(2);
            $('#discount-detector').removeClass('light-me-green');
        }
    }
  }
  value = (value <= flow) ? flow : value - 1;
  document.getElementById(el).value = value;
}
function validateQty(el,type,min,max){
  var value = el.value;
  switch(type) {
    case 'number':
        value = (value > max) ? max : value;
        value = (value < min) ? min : value;
        break;
    case n:

        break;
    default:
        el.value = value;
  }
  el.value = value;
}
```